# Syntax error: IBOutletCollection

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am trying to declare an IBOutletCollection.
What I want to do is to manage multiple buttons in a way that I don't have to declare them one per one.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface WindowManager : NSObject 
{
    @private
    IBOutlet NSTextField* textField;
    IBOutletCollection (NSButton) NSArray* buttonsArray;
}

@property (nonatomic , retain) IBOutletCollection (NSButton) NSArray *buttonsArray;

- (void) awakeFromNib;

@end
```

I get these errors:

```
type name requires a specifier or qualifier

expected ; at end of declaration
```

And I don't understand the reason.
I want to have this situation: when the .xib file is loaded, I have all the button in a NSArray so that I am able to manage them.Everytime a button is pressed I want to know which button was pressed.
Is that possibile? The problem is that I find only iPhone guides, I found an example similar to this code on an iPhone guide, saying this thing works.

Comment: IBOutletCollection is only available on iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using an IBAction instead:

```
-(IBAction)button_Clicked:(id)sender;
```

The reason is that the button that was pressed is the 'sender' of the press event.  This way you will always know what button was actually pressed.  If you want to make it even more identifiable, you can set the 'Tag' property for the buttons, so that your implementation file would look like this:

```
-(IBAction)button_Clicked:(id)sender {
    switch([sender tag]) {
        case 1:
            // do stuff
            break;
        //etc.....
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

You can assign any number of controls to use the action.  I hope this helps.

Comment: There's a problem: the code doesn't work if I try this way.
So for debugging I tried to print with NSLog the sender tag and it's null.Why?

Comment: In your interface file (.h) you have the `-(IBAction)button_Clicked:(id)sender;` declared correct?  Then you should have the actual method declared in the implementation file (.m).  Once you do that, you need to connect all of the buttons to the method from the .xib file.  The `tag` property is an `NSInteger` and should never be null...unless the sender is not of the `NSButton` type and there isn't a `tag` property, which would then return a nil id object.